# running a node.js application on iis using HttpPlatformHandler

Tags: node.js, iis

I am trying to run a "Hello World" sample node.js server on iis:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello World\n");
})
server.listen(3000);
console.log('server is running');
```

using this web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\username\Tests\nodeHandlerTest\app.js">
            <environmentVariables>
            </environmentVariables>            
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and it doesn't work! Any idea what is the problem with my `web.config` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For the port, the module will start up the process on a random port that you can access with `%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%`.  So you should map it to a Node env variable, otherwise you will get address in use errors when IIS tries to start up multiple Node processes when it recycles.
- The path to your `app.js` should be specified in the `arguments` attribute.

So your `app.js` should look like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello World\n");
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
console.log('server is running on port: ' + port);
```

And `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform 
           stdoutLogEnabled="true"
           stdoutLogFile=".\node.log"
           startupTimeLimit="20"
           processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
           arguments=".\app.js">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>            
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note that, as of v1.2 relative paths are supported, if the path begins with '.' the path is considered to be relative to the site root, hence the  `.\` to the log and app.js file.  More info [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference).

Comment: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` might break on some machines. See my post for more details, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Answer (score -1):

An example of web.config file, using argument tag for the command file :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>   
        <httpPlatform forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" stdoutLogEnabled="false" processesPerApplication="1" startupTimeLimit="120" processPath="C:\ruby2_jruby\bin\jruby.exe" arguments=" -J-XX:+TieredCompilation -J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -J-noverify -J-Xmn256m -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx512m -J-server -J-XX:+UseParallelGC -J-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -J-Djruby.jit.threshold=10 -J-Djruby.jit.max=16384 -J-XX:CompileThreshold=10 -J-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M -J-d64 -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -S puma --env production --dir C:\inetpub\wwwroot\jruby\redmine -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -t 10:20 ">
            <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="JAVA_HOME" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8\bin\java.exe" /> 
        <environmentVariable name="RAILS_ENV" value="production" />
        <environmentVariable name="RACK_ENV" value="production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /> 
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" password="***" userName="***" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```